# How to define querySelectorAll inside JS iteration

Tags: javascript, polymer, iteration

Inside Polymer, I need to find all `<a>` with certain class names and add their ID as innerHTML but I don't seem to be able to figure it out. The class names are in an external json file, loaded via iron-ajax.

Right now I have this function:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'settings-menu',
  properties: {
            paragraphTitles: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true,
              value: function(){return []}
            },
            selectedParagraph: {
                type: String,
                computed: "_computePar(paragraphTitles)"
            }
  },
  _computePar: function(paragraphTitles) {
    for (var key in paragraphTitles) {
            var refs = document.querySelectorAll('a.',key);
            refs.forEach(item => item.innerHTML = item.id);
    }
  },
```

The json file that is loaded into paragraphTitles looks something like this:

```
{
        "as": "Page numbers in Author1, 1972.",
        "adh-v": "Paragraph numbers in Some Other Author 1978",
        "apz": "Paragraph numbers in Author 3",
        "cps": "Paragraph numbers in Author 4, 1952-62",
}
```

The search string for the querySelectorAll is obviously wrong, but how do I enter the correct search string?

Comment: did you mean `'a.' + key`?

Comment: Yes, for instance it needs to search through the json file for `a.as`, `a.adh-v`, `a.apz`, etc. So all `<a>` with these specific classes and no others.

Comment: he suggested you to replace `var refs = document.querySelectorAll('a.',key);`  with `var refs = document.querySelectorAll('a.'+key);`

Comment: Yes, I know and I did. I was just about to type it but my computer froze so it took a while. So Thanks @SergioTulentsev - I could have thought of that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually not sure what you want to archive please post some more information. But what definitly is wrong with your code is that

```
document.querySelectorAll()
```

is better not used since this will break Shadow Dom. Instead use

```
Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll()
```